# rounding to two decimal places for currency values

Tags: acumatica

I have a couple of custom fields, they are the same and created as follows:

DB Script:

IF COL_LENGTH('ARInvoice', 'UsrNormalVat') IS NULL

BEGIN

```
    ALTER TABLE ARInvoice
    ADD [UsrNormalVat] Decimal(19,4)
```

END

ARInvoiceEntry:
`public class ARInvoiceExt : PXCacheExtension<ARInvoice>
    {

        #region UsrNormalVat
        public abstract class usrNormalVat : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected Decimal? _UsrNormalVat;
        [PXDBDecimal(2)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Normal Vat")]
        public virtual Decimal? UsrNormalVat
        {
            get
            {
                return this._UsrNormalVat;
            }
            set
            {
                this._UsrNormalVat = value;
            }
        }
}`

So depending on the data on an invoice the value may be UsrNormalVAT = 39.6758 where the TaxTotal = 39.6800

Any idea how to set the fields to round to two decimal places?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

`UsrNormalVat = PXDBCurrencyAttribute.Round(cache, row, (decimal)(UsrNormalVatBase * VATRate), CMPrecision.TRANCURY);`